# Disallow multi-window (split-screen) without setting `android:resizeableActivity` in the manifest

Tags: android, android-source

We are an OEM working with an external app developer. The app they have written locks to portrait with `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in its manifest. It also disallows resizing with `android:resizeableActivity="false"`.

Our device is designed for use in vehicles and as such operates as a vehicle control head. It does not support portrait mode; any apps that request it are resized to allow landscape display. Because of the aforementioned attributes in the manifest, the app always displays in screen compatibility mode, with the UI squashed in the centre of the screen.

We've tried a number of different solutions. We tried setting the orientation programmatically instead of the in the manifest, but this causes an initial rotation on some handset devices that the app already supports, and which was deemed unacceptable by their QA team. They maintain that the attributes in their manifest mentioned above MUST NOT be removed.

Has anyone been in this situation? Are there any fixes on the application side that we've missed? Would they have to revise their decision to statically disallow resizing?

Comment: I honestly can't see a system doing much better than that compatibility mode, if all those constraints are to be held in place. If the app doesn't support landscape mode, isn't resizeable and the device doesn't support portrait mode, then I simply can't see a better way out than that ...

Comment: Given that [Android Automotive OS requires a portrait and a landscape layout](https://developers.google.com/cars/design/automotive-os/apps/media/create-your-app/design-settings#layout_requirements) this may in the end be a business level question if such an app is appropriate for a car environment.

Comment: Have you checked this config ? config_supportsMultiWindow 
I am not really able to relate the description of the question and the question title itself.
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/multi-window#implementation